# try! won't compile mismatched types

Tags: macros, rust

Why doesn't this Rust code compile?

```
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::path::Path;

fn do_job(path: &Path) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut files: Vec<&Path> = Vec::new();

    for entry in try!(fs::read_dir(path)) {
        entry = try!(entry);
    }
}
```

it's very similar to code in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html).

compile error:

```
<std macros>:3:43: 3:46 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::result::Result<std::fs::DirEntry, std::io::error::Error>`,
    found `std::fs::DirEntry`
(expected enum `core::result::Result`,
    found struct `std::fs::DirEntry`) [E0308]
<std macros>:3 $ crate:: result:: Result:: Ok ( val ) => val , $ crate:: result:: Result::
                                                         ^~~
src/main.rs:13:17: 13:28 note: in this expansion of try! (defined in <std macros>)
<std macros>:3:43: 3:46 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:12:5: 14:6 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::result::Result<(), std::io::error::Error>`,
    found `()`
(expected enum `core::result::Result`,
    found ()) [E0308]
src/main.rs:12     for entry in try!(fs::read_dir(path)) {
src/main.rs:13         entry = try!(entry);
src/main.rs:14     }
src/main.rs:12:5: 14:6 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want a new binding for each directory entry in your loop:

```
for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
    let entry = entry?;
}
```

this new binding will shadow the one introduced in the `for` expression.

The type of `entry` introduced by the loop is `Result<DirEntry>` which you are trying to unwrap using `?` (formerly `try!`). However you are attempting to assign the resulting `DirEntry` to a binding with type `Result<DirEntry>`, hence the error.

The second error indicates that the return value from your function does not match the declared type of `io::Result<()>`. You can simply return `Ok(())`:

```
fn do_job(path: &Path) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut files: Vec<&Path> = Vec::new();

    for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        //process entry
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: @VictorAurélio - You are missing the `let` before `entry`.

Comment: I added the `let` but there's error yet (the second error only).

Comment: @VictorAurélio - You need to return a value from your function e.g. `Ok(())`.